# No realiza la busqueda en tablas

Tags: php

```
$instruccion = mysql_query("SELECT id_cliente FROM inspeccion WHERE '" . $_POST['concepto'] . "  LIKE '%" . $_POST['busqueda'] . "%' AND id_cia='".$cia."'
                           INNER JOIN clientes ON id_cliente.clientes = id_cliente.inspeccion 
                           ORDER BY id_cliente DESC LIMIT 1,1");
```

Buenas tardes aqui otra vez me podran dar una mano con este inner join el cual cae directo a fallo de consulta. De antemano gracias

Answer (score 0):

En el inner join es al reves `ON clientes.id_cliente = inspeccion.id_cliente` en lugar de `ON id_cliente.clientes = id_cliente.inspeccion`
en el tabla.campo siempre va primero la tabla y luego el campo

Además me parece que te marcará un error de ambigúedad dado que ambas tablas tienen un campo id_cliente, debes especificar uno, por ejemplo  en lugar de `SELECT id_cliente` poner `SELECT clientes.id_cliente`
igual en el order by ORDER BY `clientes.id_cliente`